# Convert a string with numbers to pure integers

Tags: php, arrays, type-conversion

I am a PHP noob. I couldn't work out how to convert a list of numbers in a string to pure integers.

That is the exact(!) string I got:

```
" 70, 51, 53, "
```

That's what it should look like after conversion:

```
70, 51, 53
```

What I want to have is an output of:

```
<? $featureIDs = array(70, 51, 53) ?>
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Title says you want pure integers and question asks for a comma-delimited string. Which is wrong? What PHP code have you composed so far?

Comment: I have edited my original question! thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the quotes in your example input were really meant to be part of the string, but if they were the following will work (it will strip out anything which isn't a number, or comma from the input).

```
$string = '" 70, 51, 53, "';
$output = explode(',',preg_replace("/[^0-9,]/", "", $string));
foreach($output as $k => $v) {
    if (!$v) {
        unset($output[$k]);
    }
}
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: The "" are not part of the string! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [explode()](https://www.php.net/explode) function:

```
$numbers = explode(',', '70, 51, 53');
```

Once you have them in an array, since PHP is loosely typed, you can use them as integers or strings. The trailing `,` may cause a problem, so you may want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ a = " 70, 51, 53, ";
$integerArray = explode(',', trim($a , " ," ) );
```

trim() will clear out all commas and whitespaces from beginning and end of the string, 
explode will separate string by commas to separate strings in array, and as php treats numeric strings same as numbers, this will be right:

```
$integerArray[0] + 30 == 100
```

Answer (score 0):

First: remove all spaces by using

`$string = str_replace( ' ', '', $string );`

Then, split the string into each element:

`$featureIDs = explode( ',', $string );`

Finally, turn all strings into integers:

`array_walk( $featureIDs , 'intval' );`

Comment: This outputs "Bool(True)":
<? $pages = " 70, 51, 53, " ?>
<? $string = str_replace( ' ', '', $pages ); ?>
<? $numbers = explode( ',', $string ); ?>

<? $featuredIDs = array_walk( $numbers, 'intval' );  ?>

Comment: no, $featureIDs contains the integers, as array_walk uses the reference. Changed the naming in my answer

Comment: you don't have to turn strings to integers, php interprets strings as integers already

Comment: I know, but he requested for pure Integers, and not a string containing an Integer. And in that case you could just ignore the last line and it would be fine, too

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match_all(), fetch all "sequences of digits".

```
$input = " 70, 51, 53, ";

$ids = array();
if (preg_match_all('(\d+)', $input, $matches)) {
  $ids = $matches[0];
}

var_dump($ids);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "70"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "51"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "53"
}
```